# Different settings in blendfile

Tags: texturing, materials, 3d-view

I watched a tutorial on PBR (Physically Based Rendering (I guess)) - http://www.cgmasters.net/free-tutorials/realtime-pbr-in-blender/ and when I downloaded the file some setting were kinda different.
 I couldn't put reflection maps on the objects because the tab "Mapping" is missing. Also, there's Real-time HDR Image which blew me away since nobody did it (youtube videos). I replicated the world setup from Cycles since some nodes from Cycles seem to work in Real-time - GLSL (which is awesome), but it didn't work (the texture wasn't 360 like in the blendfile from cgmasters).
In the nodes for the sphere whatever texture I click the specular map doesn't change in the Material Preview.

Is the code manipulated specifically for PBR or am I missing something obvious?

Also, I really need real-time HDRI so please help!

Update:
I realized it's a test build version (2.78), it doesn't work with 2.77a, but the sphere texture still puzzles me (It doesn't update when I change it from the nodes), but it's a complicated setup so I should probably make a good study of it.

I almost forgot - I still can't aply an HDR image in the viewport (make it 360) and if it works from the cgmasters file, then it's possible. Please help!

The issue
[image]

Blend File is here:

[image]

Comment: I've added your blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ Please always use that site for uploads, as they guarantee the file will be around for a looooooong time. pasteall links will expire at some point.

Comment: @aliasguru Thanks. I'll check out the site

Answer (score 3):

Those mapping settings will only appear if you are **NOT** using nodes to define your material in Blender Internal. Uncheck the button marked in red on the material tab to get the settings back as they are in the first screenshot:

[image: mapping back]

It makes sense, as you would - when using nodes - drop in a mapping node to the node graph to do the same thing. That's why the panels (and many other options) disappear.

### Edit

Regarding the HDRI, the ability to show an HDRI directly in the Viewport has been added to Blender in 2.77, you can get the latest release (currently 2.77a) on the Blender website: http://www.blender.org. If you want the HDRI to **also reflect** on the objects, you'll need a development build from https://builder.blender.org/download/

Here is a screenshot taken from Blender 2.77a:

[image]

and this is the same scene in the current development build:

[image]

Comment: @Vladimir regarding HDRI I don't understand your question. Also, if that is something separate (not linked to the settings you were looking for), please consider asking another question just regarding your HDRI issue. Multi-questions are not allowed on BSE.

Comment: In the World tab when I check horison the image shows in the viewport as it is (it's not 360 like in the video). But in the blendfile from cgmasters it works. I can't figure out why. I'll also update the question

Comment: Do you just press on "horison" for the hdri, I'm still having trouble - http://pasteall.org/pic/index.php?id=106270

Comment: No I don't press anything, I just open your file. Did you test it with the current release candidate for Blender 2.78, available from http://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.78/ ? The world displays fine, the cube as well. The sphere has some trouble with the material, but I'm uncertain where this is coming from. If you use the cube material on the sphere, it shades. Also if you select the Output node for the reflection only on the sphere material, it works. Must be something in the node setup.

Comment: @Vladimir please test again with the 1.78 Release candidate (link in comment before), I simply download your Blend file without changing anything at first. With the exception of the Sphere, everything just works. BTW what are your machine specs?